# Перескакивает курсор в input при добавлении текста

Tags: jquery, input, курсор

Всем добрый день, хочу сделать живой поиск как у Яндекса, все уже почти получилось, но если "переходить" клавишами клавиатуры вверх и вниз по списку предложенных вариантов поиска, то курсор в `input` переходит то в конец текста, то в начало. Соответственно если нажимать клавишу вниз, то курсор встает в конец текста в поле input, если нажать клавишу вверх, то курсор встанет сначала в начало текста в поле `input`, а только при повторном нажатии будет "переходить" по списку. Переходить в кавычках потому как просто имитируется выбор словосочетания в списке путем выделения цвета. 
Если убрать код вставки выбранного текста в поле `input`, то все нормально, курсор стоит на прежнем месте. `$('#search').val($("li:eq("+poz+")").text());`

Вот часть кода для "перемещения" по списку вариантов словосочетания:

```
$('#search').keydown(function(e){
    $("ul#resSearch").children().each(function() {
$(this).css( "color", "black" );
});

razmer=$("ul#resSearch li").length;  
 if (poz==-1){poz=razmer;}     
    else if (poz==razmer){poz=0;} 
        if (e.keyCode == '40') {

       $('ul#resSearch').find("li:eq("+poz+")").css( "color", "red" );
       $('#search').val($("li:eq("+poz+")").text());
       poz++;}
 if (e.keyCode == '38') {
     poz--;
       $('ul#resSearch').find("li:eq("+poz+")").css( "color", "red" );
       $('#search').val($("li:eq("+poz+")").text());
       }    
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

[.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)
Слыхали?

```
$('#search').keydown(function(e){
  $("ul#resSearch").children().each(function() {
    $(this).css( "color", "black" );
  });
  razmer=$("ul#resSearch li").length;  
  if(e.keyCode == '40'||e.keyCode == '38'){
     e.preventDefault();
  }
  if(e.keyCode == '40') {
    poz++;
    if(poz==razmer){
      poz=0;
    }
  }
  if(e.keyCode == '38') {
    poz--;
    if(pos==-1){
      poz=razmer-1;
   }
  }
  $('ul#resSearch').find("li:eq("+poz+")").css( "color", "red" );
  $('#search').val($("li:eq("+poz+")").text());
});
```

Comment: Благодарствую, Сударь, помогли, курсор остается в одном положении, но остается еще один вопрос: если идти по списку клавишей вниз, а потом клавишей вверх, то надо нажать два раза клавишу вверх, чтобы выделилось верхнее словосочетание и дальше все идет хорошо, словосочетания выделяются с первого раза?